# MergeSorting LinkedList in Java recursively

Tags: java, linked-list, mergesort, singly-linked-list

So the task is to implement a linked-list and merge-sort which sorts linked-lists. I am fully aware that in industry I most likely won't have to implement any of these but I feel it's a good way to practice Java. Here is what I've got up to this point:

**Node class:**

```
public class Node<E extends Comparable<E>>
    {

    public E data;
    public Node<E> next;

    public Node(E data)
    {
        this.data = data;
        next = null;
    }

    public void printData()
    {
        System.out.print(data + " ");
    }
}
```

**LinkedList class:**

```
public class LinkedList<E extends Comparable<E>>
{

    protected Node<E> root;
    protected int size = 0;

    public LinkedList()
    {
        root = null;
    }


    public void addBeg(E e)
    {

        Node<E> newNode = new Node<E>(e);
        newNode.next = root;
        root = newNode;

        size++;
    }

    public Node deleteBeg()
    {
        Node<E> temp = root;
        if(!isEmpty())
        {
            root = root.next; 
            size--;
        }
        return temp;
    }

    public void setRoot(Node<E> newRoot)
    {
        root = newRoot;
    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return root == null;
    }

    public Node<E> getRoot()
    {
        return root;
    }

    public void printList()
    {
        Node<E> cur = root;   
        while(cur!=null)
            {
                cur.printData();
                cur=cur.next;
            }
        System.out.println();        
    }
}
```

**MergeSorter Class:**

```
public class MergeSorter<E extends Comparable<E>>
{

    public MergeSorter()
    {

    }

    private void split(LinkedList<E> list, LinkedList<E> firHalf, LinkedList<E> secHalf)
    {
        //if 0 or only 1 elements in the list - it doesn't seem to work, however
        if(list.getRoot() == null || list.getRoot().next == null)firHalf = list;
        else{
            Node<E> slow = list.getRoot(); 
            Node<E> fast = list.getRoot().next; 
            while(fast!=null)
            {
                fast = fast.next;
                if(fast!=null)
                {
                    fast = fast.next;
                    slow = slow.next;
                } 
            }
            //If I use the following line firHalf list is empty when in the caller of this method (it's not in this method, however). Don't understand why ):
            //firHalf = list; 
            firHalf.setRoot(list.getRoot());
            secHalf.setRoot(slow.next);
            slow.next = null;
        }

    }



    private LinkedList<E> merge(LinkedList<E> a, LinkedList<E> b)
     {
        LinkedList<E> mergedList = new LinkedList<E>();    
        Node<E> dummy = new Node<E>(null);
        Node<E> tail = dummy;

        while(true)
        {         
            if(a.getRoot() == null){
                tail.next = b.getRoot();
                break;
            }
            else if(b.getRoot() == null){
                tail.next = a.getRoot();
                break;
            }

            else 
            {
                if(a.getRoot().data.compareTo(b.getRoot().data) <= 0)
                {
                    tail.next = a.getRoot();
                    tail = tail.next;
                    a.setRoot(a.getRoot().next);
                }

                else
                {   
                    tail.next = b.getRoot();
                    tail = tail.next;
                    b.setRoot(b.getRoot().next);
                }
                tail.next = null;
            }

        }
        mergedList.setRoot(dummy.next);
        return mergedList;
    }

    public void mergeSort(LinkedList<E> list)
    {
        Node<E> root = list.getRoot();
        LinkedList<E> left  = new LinkedList<E>();
        LinkedList<E> right = new LinkedList<E>();

        if(root == null || root.next == null) return; //base case
        split(list, left, right); //split

        mergeSort(left);
        mergeSort(right);

        list = merge(left, right); // when this mergeSort returns this list should be  
                                   // referenced by the left or right variable of the 
                                   // current mergeSort call (but it isn't!)
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Java (coming from a C background) so I am sincerely sorry in advance if my code is utterly false. When I test the split and merge methods in the MergeSorter class independently, everything seems to work (splitting a list consisting of 0 or 1 element is not working and is driving me crazy but this is not needed for merge-sorting). The mergeSort method, however, is not working and I can't seem to figure out way. I tried to debug it myself and there's seems to be a problem when two halves are merged into one list and then the recursion returns. The newly merged list should be referenced by either the left or right variable of the current mergeSort call but instead I get only the last element instead of the whole list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method arguments in Java are always passed by value.

This can be a bit confusing, since objects are always accessed via references, so you might think they're passed by reference; but they're not. Rather, the references are passed by value.

What this means is, a method like this:

```
public void methodThatDoesNothing(Object dst, Object src) {
    src = dst;
}
```

actually does nothing. It modifies its local variable `src` to refer to the same object as the local variable `dst`, but those are just local variables that disappear when the function returns. They're completely separate from whatever variables or expressions were passed into the method.

So, in your code, this:

```
firHalf = list;
```

does not really do anything. I guess what you want is:

```
while (! firHalf.isEmpty()) {
    firHalf.deleteBeg();
}
if (! list.isEmpty()) {
    firHalf.addBeg(list.root().data);
}
```

which modifies the objected referred to by `firHalf` so it has the same zero-or-one elements as `list`.

Comment: Aaah, I get your point. Thanks a lot! However, it seems to me that that's too much code for such a simple task. Wouldn't this:

firHalf.setRoot(list.getRoot());

do the same job? And I suppose pass by value is also the reason why merging in my mergeSort method is not working properly when recursion returns? (:

Comment: So in my mergeSort method I added a new LinkedList<E> mergedList to store the merged list of left and right: mergedList = merge(left, right), and then I set the root of list to be the same as the root of this mergedList by list.setRoot(mergedList.getRoot()) and it worked! However, I feel my solution is quite over-complicated (compared to what it would look written in C, for example). Is there something which can be improved in my code? Thanks again! (:

Comment: @user3192253: `firHalf.setRoot(list.getRoot())` would set `firHalf` and `list` to have the same actual root node, not just the same root value. This means that if someone were to write `list.getRoot().value = ...` or `list.getRoot().next = ...`, that would alter both lists. So . . . yes, you should do that, but only *after* you change your `Node` class to be immutable, so that it can be safely shared between multiple lists. (That is: `Node.value` and `Node.next` should both be declared `final` and initialized in the constructor.)

Comment: (Alternatively, you could give your `Node` class a method that recursively copies a list, and then write `firHalf.setRoot(list.getRoot().clone())`. But I think the immutability route is better.)

Comment: Okay, thanks a bunch.. again. If, however, I change `Node` to be immutable, then certain algorithms like reversing a linked list or appending two lists will be much harder to implement (since both require changing `Node.next`). If this is declared as final, then I would need to create an entire new linked list of new nodes instead of just changing the node references of the current one ):

Comment: Also, I am not entirely sure about this, but if we look at two linked-lists abstractly and they have the same root, then essentially, they are the same list right? So it's seems reasonable to me that changing 'one of the lists' will affect the 'other'.

Comment: Re: your first comment: Correct. If your lists are immutable, then "reversing" or "appending" means creating a new list that's a reversed-or-appended copy. Re: your second comment: Yes, that's what I'm saying. You don't want to write `firHalf.setRoot(list.getRoot())`, because that would make them the same list, which isn't what you want. You just want to set `firHalf` to contain the current contents of `list`.

Comment: Maybe I don't get the split part of mergeSort then. I am taking  `list` and I am splitting it into `firHalf` and `secHalf`. I don't need `list` anymore. That's the way I would have written the `split` function in C (using reference pointers). Maybe it looks weird written like this in Java. Maybe I should rewrite it so it takes a `LinkedList<E>` and returns a pair of linked lists (which would mean that I have to create a new class named `PairOfLinkedLists` etc..). I am sorry.. I am still not used to the language I suppose.

Comment: @user3192253: No need to apologize. Re: "I am taking `list` and I am splitting it into `firHalf` and `secHalf`. I don't need `list` anymore": Yeah, I find that weird. There's no reason for `split` to destroy `list`.

Comment: Yeah, I find it a bit weird myself. But, in a strange way, it makes sense (if you split an apple you get 2 halves, not a new apple and two halves :). And, I am not entirely sure, but that's exactly how `split` in an efficient MergeSort should behave (splitting a list into two by destroying it), right?

Comment: @user3192253: The way garbage-collection works in Java, there's not much reason to reuse `Node` objects (which is all it means to "destroy" `list`). Unless you've specifically profiled and determined otherwise in your case, I think the benefits of immutability will most outweigh the benefits of object reuse. (Besides, if you're really concerned about efficiency, I think the most efficient approach is to copy the list into an array, do a bottom-up merge-sort, and then copy back. That eliminates all the "split" steps entirely.)